# Why is fsspec an optional dependency, when you need it to read a csv file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I use the `pandas` package quite a bit, so I've made it globally available on my main work computer. I did this quite awhile ago, so I can't recall all the details to what I did when installing in the past, but I don't remember having to take an extra step in installing the optional dependency, `fsspec`.

I recently tried to get a little work done at home, and I had to `pip install pandas` again on another computer, and I was surprised to see that reading from a <s>local</s> csv file failed because `fsspec` was considered an optional dependency.

What's the reasoning behind making it optional instead of automatically installing it as a required dependency?

***edit:*** It turns out I just fat-fingered the path and put `c://` instead of `c:/`. I'm assuming the extra slash set a flag to recognize the rest of the path as a remote file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html?highlight=storage_options#reading-writing-remote-files):

> **All URLs which are not local files or HTTP(s) are handled by fsspec**,
> if installed, and its various filesystem implementations (including
> Amazon S3, Google Cloud, SSH, FTP, webHDFS…).

As to why is optional - [it's developer's decision](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33452), but I would expect that as it is not required if you don't work with remote files, you don't need it, so they decided t leave it optional.

Comment: See edit above^ I'm marking as solution since it led me to take a second look at file-path, and was a pretty informative answer.

Comment: I was just about to write that i am not able to replicate and have no problem reading local file without `fsspec`.